# No native Aggregation of mongodb in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a monogodb collection which I can query like this:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.answers.aggregate([
     {$group: { _id: { owner: "$owner", locked: "$locked" } } }
]);
{ "_id" : { "owner" : "qCkecS4s8wjSRL4YS", "locked" : true } }
{ "_id" : { "owner" : "MQCMpT8xwh5ripBLA", "locked" : false } }
```

This works perfectly in meteor:

```
var result = Answers.find( {_id: id} )
```

But when I do this in meteor I get an error:

```
var result = Answers.find( {_id: id}).aggregate([ {$group: { _id: { owner: "$owner", locked: "$locked" } } }  ]);
```

I have seen that there are packages around to support aggregation but is that really needed. I use Meteor 1.1.0.1 with mongodb 3.x

---

Here is an other example:

```
var userSendin = Answers.find( {_id: id} );

var userSendin2 = Answers.aggregate([ { $match:{_id: id} }  ]);
```

Both should have the same result but only the .find() works for me ..

Any idea why? I have no usable error message just Error in line xx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a package to support aggregation. There are a number out there, most are server-side only and nonreactive. One that is reliable is from meteorhacks. `meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate`.

Comment: Thx! Just to understand: why can I not use plain mongodb in meteor?

Comment: When you perform CRUD operations in Meteor they are not done directly on a database. Instead, they are performed on 'Collections' which are a database abstraction that allow Meteor to perform its reactivity and other magic. For ordinary reads and writes the syntax is identical and no one will feel a difference. But as you move towards edge cases and things like mapReduce and aggregation, you may need packages etc. Check out http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/collections

Comment: Does this count for client and server?

Comment: I'm not sure in what sense you are asking. Collections exist on both client and server. Aggregation availability will depend on the package. Queries are largely the same but not always identical. The Meteor docs do a nice job of dividing the API by command into 'client', 'server' and 'anywhere'.